# Arduino Due as Triggered DMA SPI Slave is possible?

Tags: arduino-due, spi, sam3x

Is it possible for arduino Due to act as **DMA-SPI-slave device** which can exchange SPI data (**uint16_t TX[10] and RX[10]**) in **triggered slave mode**?

I have a setup in which time period is very short (~500uS/cycle). so I need to exchange data with another Microcontroller (acting as 'Master') within the mensioned time limit. Some other tasks are also to be processed. This is why I have to go for DMA and fast data transfer without intervension of processor. All the codes available are to be used in Master mode of SPI. ***Not a single one is in SLAVE mode.***
I wrote a code but I cannot implement a transfer triggered by SPI hardware. Also how to implement data transfer complete Interrupt after all 10 datas(16bit) have been transferred and received?
Here is my initialization code:

```
    void DMAslaveBegin()
{
    // Configure the pins for SPI in peripheral mode
    PIO_Configure(
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MOSI].pPort,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MOSI].ulPinType,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MOSI].ulPin,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MOSI].ulPinConfiguration);
    PIO_Configure(
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MISO].pPort,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MISO].ulPinType,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MISO].ulPin,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_MISO].ulPinConfiguration);
    PIO_Configure(
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SCK].pPort,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SCK].ulPinType,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SCK].ulPin,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SCK].ulPinConfiguration);
    PIO_Configure(
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SS0].pPort,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SS0].ulPinType,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SS0].ulPin,
        g_APinDescription[PIN_SPI_SS0].ulPinConfiguration); 
    //pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_SPI0);
#if USE_SAM3X_DMAC
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_DMAC);
    DMAC_Disable();
    DMAC->DMAC_GCFG = DMAC_GCFG_ARB_CFG_FIXED;  //Fixed priority arbiter
    DMAC_Enable();

#if USE_SAM3X_BUS_MATRIX_FIX    // not active here
    MATRIX->MATRIX_WPMR = 0x4d415400;
    MATRIX->MATRIX_MCFG[1] = 1;         //Single Access
    MATRIX->MATRIX_MCFG[2] = 1;         //Single Access
    MATRIX->MATRIX_SCFG[0] = 0x01000010;
    MATRIX->MATRIX_SCFG[1] = 0x01000010;
    MATRIX->MATRIX_SCFG[7] = 0x01000010;

#endif  // USE_SAM3X_BUS_MATRIX_FIX
#endif  // USE_SAM3X_DMAC
    //  initialize SPI controller - Slave mode
    SPI.begin(_pin);
    SPI_Disable(SPI0);
    REG_SPI0_CR = SPI_CR_SWRST;     // reset SPI
    REG_SPI0_CR = SPI_CR_SPIEN;     // enable SPI
    REG_SPI0_MR = 0x10;              // DLYBCS=0, PCS=0, MODFDIS=1, PS=0, MSTR=0(slave)
    REG_SPI0_CSR = 0x80;            // DLYBCT=0, DLYBS=0, SCBR=0, 16 bit transfer, Mode 0/1
    REG_SPI0_IDR = ~SPI_IDR_RDRF;
    REG_SPI0_IER = SPI_IDR_RDRF;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI0_IRQn);
    SPI_Enable(SPI0);
}
```

Is this a valid condition for DMA? 
How can I utilize **SPI ISR handler like system in DMA** for my code so that the complete transaction (simultaneous Transmit & Receive) becomes fully automatic without processor utilization?

Comment: It is more than likely possible.  However, we lowly Arduino users probably aren't knowledgeable enough about Atmel's SDK and the workings of the Due's MCU to give you the best answer. Your best source of information would probably be a dedicated Atmel ARM MCU forum. One that deals on a more professional level than Arduino.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post. but, does DMA callbacks on SPI interrupt?

Comment: What does the datasheet / SDK API manual say?

Comment: PDC can employ Handler, but I couldn't find DMA Handler for SPI slave mode. The datasheet DMAC section is also messy.

Comment: I don't think DMA really cares about what "mode" SPI is running in.

Comment: Looking at the datasheet though it only talks about dma in master mode, so maybe it cant...

Comment: Your point of view might be right about "DMA really cares about what "mode" SPI is running in".@Majenko. We are using SPI RX and TX Buffers as Source and Destination respectively. So, the SPI hardware is handling all data transfer and Interrupts; after this, DMA takes over for interaction with memory. The DMA and SPI both have a seperate clock and need to be activated seperately. This is the proof that two modules are seperate. Also, DMA is acting on behalf of processor, so it needs to be in master mode. Then, how we can enable and access "Chained buffer transmit complete" interrupt?

Comment: I think I have discovered a solution while searching:
https://github.com/avrxml/asf/blob/master/sam/drivers/spi/spi_dmac_slave_example/spi_dmac_slave_example.c It is an example for atmel's sam3X8EK. But the MCU cores are same. Though the code serves different purpose, we can manage to mold it in the direction we need. Only thing remained to do is to push an array through it.
Fellows, what do you think?